# Array entry used in function turns from nan to 0 numpy python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I made a simple function that produces a weighted average of several time series using supplied weights. It is designed to handle missing values (NaNs), which is why I am not using numpy's supplied average function.

However, when I feed it my array containing missing values, the array has its nan values replaced by 0s! I would have assumed that since I am changing the name of the array and it is not a global variable this should not happen. I want my X array to retain its original form including the nan value

I am a relative novice using python (obviously).

Example:

````
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, np.nan]]) # 3 time series to be weighted together
weights = np.array([[1,1,1]]) # simple example with weights for each series as 1

def WeightedMeanNaN(Tseries, weights):
    ## calculates weighted mean 
    N_Tseries = Tseries
    Weights = np.repeat(weights, len(N_Tseries), axis=0) # make a vector of weights matching size of time series
    loc = np.where(np.isnan(N_Tseries)) # get location of nans
    Weights[loc] = 0
    N_Tseries[loc] = 0

    Weights = Weights/Weights.sum(axis=1)[:,None] # normalize each row so that weights sum to 1
    WeightedAve = np.multiply(N_Tseries,Weights)
    WeightedAve = WeightedAve.sum(axis=1)
    return WeightedAve

WeightedMeanNaN(Tseries = X, weights = weights)

Out[161]: array([2. , 2. , 1.5])

In:X
Out: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 0.]]) # no longer nan!! ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Where you call

```
loc = np.where(np.isnan(N_Tseries)) # get location of nans
    Weights[loc] = 0
    N_Tseries[loc] = 0
```

You remove all NaNs and set them to zeros.

To reverse this you could iterate over the array and replace zeros with NaNs.
However, this would also set regular zeros to Nans.

Comment: But I am setting nan in N_Tseries to 0, not X. Plus even if the variable had the same name, it's unclear why this would have a global effect on anything other than the returned variable.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is a mistake caused by me being used to working in Matlab. Python treats arguments supplied to the function as pointers to the original object. In contrast, Matlab creates copies that are discarded when the function ends.

I solved my problem by adding ".copy()" when assigning variables in the function, so that the first line in the function above becomes:

N_Tseries = Tseries.copy().

However, one thing that puzzles me is that some people have suggested that using Tseries[:] should also create a copy of Tseries rather than a pointer to the original variable. This did not work for me though.

I found this answer useful:
[Python function not supposed to change a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372778/python-function-not-supposed-to-change-a-global-variable)